# Record the time a user was logged in with Authlogic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authlogic

I need to add a report in my app of how much time a User is logged in.

I know it will not be accurate because if the User closes the browser, the session will live around 30 minutes more.

But with all the limitations, how do I know when a session has expired and record that time even if there is no request present?

Answer (score 1):

As far as managing the session, the means of how you would access it could vary.  But one way you can probably track time is to record the time in a database field whenever the user logs in.  Then if the user logs out, record the log out time.  Then add the difference (log out time - log in time) to another total time field.  As for session expiring, you can probably assume that it expires after 30 minutes.  So the next time the user logs in, if the "log out time" field is blank, then assume the last block of time spent is the lesser of: The new "log in time" - "last log in time" or 30 minutes.

Comment: Thanks! For the last case, then I must save also the "last request" time? Because an user can be logged in 2 hours if he keeps requesting doesn't?

Comment: Good point... in that case you would want to keep track of when the user is active.  Maybe you can add a "last activity" timestamp field and put a before_action in your application_controller.rb file which updates that every time a logged in user makes a request.  In such case of the session expiring the period of activity would be:

Activity Time = The lesser of: (Last activity time + 30 min - Last log in time) or (Last log out - Last log in time)